# different ways to see why this matrix limit is correct

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, limits

given that $0 < a < 1$ it follows that:
 $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\begin{pmatrix}
 a & (1-a) \\
 (1-a) & a  
\end{pmatrix}^n = \begin{pmatrix}
 0.5 & 0.5 \\
 0.5 & 0.5  
\end{pmatrix}$$

I am thinking of different ways to see why is that the case(even intuitively, without official proof).

one of them for example is looking at this matrix as  transition matrix of Markov chain. the one can see why the limit has to be the given.

but I'm pretty sure there are more ways to see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}a&(1-a)\\(1-a)&a\end{bmatrix}
$$
Note that $A=PDP^{-1}$ where
\begin{align*}
P &=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}&
D &=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\,a-1\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
A^n &= \underbrace{(PDP^{-1})\dotsb(PDP^{-1})}_{n\text{ times}} \\
&= PD^nP^{-1} \\
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&(2\,a-1)^n\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1/2&1/2\\-1/2&1/2\end{bmatrix} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}1&-(2\,a-1)^n\\ 1&(2\,a-1)^n\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}1+(2\,a-1)^n&1-(2\,a-1)^n\\1-(2\,a-1)^n&1+(2\,a-1)^n\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Can you use this to compute $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}A^n$?

The process of finding a diagonal matrix $D$ and an invertible matrix $P$ such that $A=PDP^{-1}$ is known as [diagonalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Diagonalization). Not every matrix can be diagonalized. If a matrix can be diagonalized, then computations involving powers of the matrix become quite simple.

Comment: yes sir. that's another way of showing that.